# ImportError under two identical folder

Tags: python

I run the same command under two identical Python project on 2 PCs

`python ./main -xls nd.xls -xml nd.xml -t 1234`

PC A : works greate
PC B throws the exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main", line 21, in <module>
    from color_print import *
ImportError: No module named color_print
```

`from color_print import *`

`from debug_tool import *`

The both python edition  are 2.7

I just curious why works on PC A and failed on PC B.

I must make some mistakes.

```
.
├── common
│   ├── Common
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── color_print.py
│   │   └── debug_tool.py
│   ├── Excel
│   │   ├── Xls.pyc
│   │   ├── XlsOperation.py
│   │   ├── XlsOperation.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   └── tmpl.py
├── main
├── nd.xls
├── nd.xml
├── nd_excel.py
├── nd_excel.pyc
├── nd_xml.py
├── nd_xml.pyc
└── origin_nd.xls
```

Comment: Maybe try "from common.Common.color_print import *"

Comment: Try `from Common.color_print import *`

Comment: But I have no idea. Why works in PC A. I just use copy -a to clone the project. There is wierd

Comment: Does this happen when you make sure your working directory in the terminal is the same?